# Is this possible to change the date of next transaction in RecurringPaymentsProfile(paypal)?

Tags: php, paypal

I Have Implemented the RecurringPaymentsProfile using the API found on this link [API LINK](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/tree/master/samples/RecurringPayments)

There is a form for `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` but no any option for changing the date of next transaction.
My question is only that, is this possible to change the date of next transaction? if yes then how(i mean using which API)?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `PROFILESTARTDATE` to update the billing date.